# Datetime object

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-objects, pywhois

How do I get the year and month from a datetime.datetime object? Here is the code 
I have problems with:

```
w = whois.whois('http://stackoverflow.com')
datatime = w.expiration_date
print datatime
```

the printed object is:

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 0, 0), u'2015-12-26T19:18:07-07:00']
```

How do I get year, month, and day from the part datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 0, 0). I guess I could use regex, but there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a list object with *one* [`datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) in it, plus an ISO 8601 string. Just use attributes on the first object:

```
datatime[0].year
datatime[0].month
datatime[0].day
```

Demo:

```
>>> datatime
[datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 0, 0), u'2015-12-26T19:18:07-07:00']
>>> datatime[0]
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 0, 0)
>>> datatime[0].year
2015
>>> datatime[0].month
12
>>> datatime[0].day
26
```

Answer (score 1):

Datetime objects has `month`, `year` and `day` attributes.

```
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 print(now.day)
 print(now.month)
 print(now.year)
```

You can use calendar for get the month name:

```
import calendar
calendar.month_name[datetime.datetime.now().month]  # Output "April"
```

Comment: this is helpful for determining if the domain es experied.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get those fields separately as integers:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 0, 0)
>>> dt.year
2015
>>> dt.month
12
>>> dt.day
26
```

Or if you want to format just those fields into a string you can use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for example:

```
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2015-12-26'
```

In this case it looks like your `datatime` object is actually a two element list, with a datetime object as the first element and string as the second element.  So to get to the datetime object you would just use `datatime[0]` in place of the `dt` in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this now, here's an updated answer for Python 3.7.4 with time information:

```
>>> datatime
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2, 11, 59, 59)
>>> print(datatime)
2020-02-02 11:59:59
>>> datatime.year
2020
>>> datatime.month
2
>>> datatime.day
2
>>> datatime.hour
11
>>> datatime.minute
59
>>> datatime.second
59
>>> datatime.microsecond
0
```